# Android/ how keep Loaders synchronized across Activities

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-loader

I search for the best pattern of loading SQLite data into my components.

I'm currently in state, where all components (Activity, Fragment) loads it's data via `CursorLoader`s and `ContentProvider`. Some activities need the same data, but all uses own `CursorLoader`. This loads data multiple times, but I did not found any good solution for sharing Loader across Activities so I suppose this is the best way to go.

The problem is with refreshing the Loaders. If one Activity changes data via `ContetResolver`, it refreshes it's own Loader, but other Activities Loaders based on the same `Uri` are not refreshed.

Currently, I'm using `LocalBroadcastManager` to inform other Activities for data have changed and appropriate Activities reacts on the Broadcast according to `IntentFilter`. But this is slightly hard to maintain and I also think, that `ContentResolver()` shall take care of such task, isn't it? A'm I doing something wrong? Is there better way to keep different Activities loaders in sync?

---

**EDIT**/ my `ContentProvider` code

I created it like REST API. I supose the `query()` method is not necessary.

```
public class BeerBookContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    // resources constants
    private static final int
        COMMON_TABLE_ID = -1,
        BEER = 0,
        BEER_ID = 1
        ....;

    private static final BeerBookUriHandler sURIHandler = new BeerBookUriHandler();
    static {
        sURIHandler
            .addURI(BeerTable.NAME, BEER)
            .addURI(BreweryTable.NAME, BREWERY)
            .addURI(BreweryTable.NAME + "/#/" + BeerTable.NAME, BREWERY_BEER_LIST)
            ...;
    }

    // I thing onCreate() and query() methods are not involved in this issue
    // but the rest follows

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = _mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        AdditionalTask additionalTask = null; // AdditionalTask is simple workaround for missing closures in Java 7
        boolean toSync = true; // means mark the change for later sync to the cloud
        long id = 0;
        Table table;

        int jumpTo = sURIHandler.match(uri);
        switch (jumpTo) {
            case BEER:
            case BREWERY:
            case CONSUMPTION:
            case TAP:
            case KEG:
                table = getTableForUri(uri); // takes tableName from uri
                break;
            case CREDIT:
                table = CreditTable.getInstance();
                final long userId = values.getAsLong(CreditTable.COL_USER);
                final double creditChange = values.getAsDouble(CreditTable.COL_AMOUNT);
                class UpdateUserAccountBalance extends AdditionalTask {
                    @Override
                    public void run(@Nullable String id) {
                        UserTable userTable = (UserTable) UserTable.getInstance();
                        userTable.updateAccountBalance(db, userId, creditChange);
                        setSync(db, userTable.name, userId, SyncTable.SYNC_EDITED);
                    }
                }
                additionalTask = new UpdateUserAccountBalance();
                break;
            case USER:
                table = UserTable.getInstance();
                final double initialCredit = values.getAsDouble(UserTable.COL_ACCOUNT_BALANCE);
                // every credit change updates user table,
                // so proper value will be set if AdditionalTask will run
                values.put(UserTable.COL_ACCOUNT_BALANCE, 0);
                if (initialCredit > 0) {
                    class AddCredit extends AdditionalTask {
                        @Override
                        public void run(@Nullable String id) {
                            CreditTable creditTable = (CreditTable) CreditTable.getInstance();
                            // TODO: change hardcoded note
                            long creditId = creditTable.insert(
                                    db, Long.parseLong(id), initialCredit, "Prvotní vklad", null);
                            setSync(db, creditTable.name, creditId, SyncTable.SYNC_CREATED);
                        }
                    }
                    additionalTask = new AddCredit();
                }
                break;
            case USER_CONSUMPTION:
                table = ConsumptionTable.getInstance();
                values.put(ConsumptionTable.COL_USER, uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            id = table.insert(db, values);
            if (id == -1)
                throw new SQLiteException("db.insert() failed");
            if (additionalTask != null)
                additionalTask.run(Long.toString(id));
            if (toSync)
                setSync(db, table.name, id, SyncTable.SYNC_CREATED);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return BeerBookUriHandler.getUri(table.name + "/" + id);
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = _mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        AdditionalTask additionalTask = null;
        boolean toSync = true;
        int rowsUpdated;
        Table table;
        String id = null;

        int jumpTo = sURIHandler.match(uri);
        switch (jumpTo) {
            case USER_ID:
                id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                table = getTableForUri(uri);
                break;
            case TAP_ID_KEG:
                final String tapId = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                final String kegId = id = values.getAsString(KegTable.COL_ID);
                final int stateChange = values.getAsInteger(KegTable.COL_STATE);
                table = KegTable.getInstance();
                additionalTask = new AdditionalTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(@Nullable String id) {
                        ContentValues tapValues = new ContentValues();
                        switch (stateChange) {
                            case KegTable.STATE_BUMPED:
                                tapValues.put(TapTable.COL_KEG, kegId);
                                break;
                            case KegTable.STATE_FINISHED:
                                ((KegTable)KegTable.getInstance())
                                        .finishAndAccount(db, kegId);
                            case KegTable.STATE_STOCKED:
                                tapValues.putNull(TapTable.COL_KEG);
                                break;
                        }
                        TapTable.getInstance().update(db, tapValues, TapTable.COL_ID + "=" + tapId, null);
                    }
                };
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            if (id != null) {
                if (selection != null)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Update of " + table.name + _AMBIGUOUS_SELECTION);
                table.update(db, values, id);
                if (additionalTask != null)
                    additionalTask.run(id);
                if (toSync)
                    setSync(db, table.name, Long.valueOf(id), SyncTable.SYNC_EDITED);
                rowsUpdated = 1;
            } else if (selection != null) {
                String[] updatedIds = table.update(db, values, selection, selectionArgs);
                for(String uId : updatedIds) {
                    if(additionalTask != null)
                        additionalTask.run(uId);
                    if(toSync)
                        setSync(db, table.name, Long.valueOf(uId), SyncTable.SYNC_EDITED);
                }
                rowsUpdated = updatedIds.length;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Update of " + table.name + _MISSING_SELECTION);
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = _mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        AdditionalTask additionalTask = null;
        boolean toSync = true;
        int rowsDeleted;
        String id = null;
        Table table;

        switch (sURIHandler.match(uri)) {
            case KEG_ID:
            case USER_ID:
                id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            case CONSUMPTION_KEG:
                table = getTableForUri(uri);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            if (id != null) {
                if (selection != null)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete of " + table.name + _AMBIGUOUS_SELECTION);
                table.safeRemove(db, id);
                if (additionalTask != null)
                    additionalTask.run(id);
                if (toSync)
                    setSync(db, table.name, Long.valueOf(id), SyncTable.SYNC_REMOVED);
                rowsDeleted = 1;
            } else if (selection != null) {
                String[] removedIds = table.safeRemove(db, selection, selectionArgs);
                for(String rId : removedIds) {
                    if(additionalTask != null)
                        additionalTask.run(rId);
                    if(toSync)
                        setSync(db, table.name, Long.valueOf(rId), SyncTable.SYNC_REMOVED);
                }
                rowsDeleted = removedIds.length;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete of " + table.name + _MISSING_SELECTION);
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

        return rowsDeleted;
    }

    private void setSync(SQLiteDatabase db, String foreignTable, long foreignId, int syncTableConst) {
        SyncTable syncTable = (SyncTable) SyncTable.getInstance();
        syncTable.insert(db, foreignTable, String.valueOf(foreignId), syncTableConst);
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: post your custom `ContentProvider` code

Comment: I've realized missing `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` in `delete()`, could be the trouble...

Comment: No time to test, must go to work, I'm already late, will try after 8 hours or so, but thanks!

Comment: it was you who noticed the lack of `notifyChange`, not me, BTW reading your code i got extremely thirsty : České pivo rules, (and German and Belgian) !

Comment: @pskink finally got it working and got rid off `LocalBroadcastReceiver`s. Thank you for hint where to look. I copied the `ContentProvider` from some tutorial long time ago, made many edits since then, but never noticed the `notifyChange()` method. Now I can refresh all my loaders from `ContentProvider()` which is nice. PS: Netherlands have also good stuff, and not only beer :) Cheers